# adb device - adb usb cmd shows either no device OR restarting in usb mode

Tags: android, cmd, adb, driver, windows-10

My device is a Vodafone Smart Ultra 6. I have the android SDK on my path and such, I have a sure connection between the PC and the phone, I can use it as a media device and share files between, and I have set the developer options. In addition, I have tried USB tethering, and when I do it changes from  no device to 'restarting in USB mode'

I am on lollipop 5.1 and windows 10.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You need a special USB driver for Windows to support adb.  This page has more details: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Vodafone isn't listed as one of the vendors with a driver there, though.  You may need to look at the USB VID/PID which is presented and if it matches one of the "known" IDs (such as Google's) then using the Google Windows driver may work for you.